# Unbind specific handler on a custom event listener

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery .live to listen for a custom event, ie not .click, .change, .keyup or any of the native events, but rather an event that I create using jquery .trigger.  I have several places in the application that listen for this event using .live.  I want to remove a single handler from the event.  None of the methods I've tried seem to work including, .unbind, .die, and .undelegate.  I'm using jquery 1.6 so I can't use .off.  What's the best way to accomplish this?

This is essentially the form my code takes. I call unbind first to remove the handler if it already exists.

```
OBJECT 1
{
    myNameSpace.MY_CUSTOM_EVENT_STRING = "my_event";

    $cachedFieldObject.trigger(myNameSpace.MY_CUSTOM_EVENT_STRING);
}

OBJECT 2
{
    function myfunctionName(var1) {myObject.myObjectsFunction()}

    $("#divID").find(".fieldClass").unbind(myNameSpace.MY_CUSTOM_EVENT_STRING, myfunctionName).live(myNameSpace.MY_CUSTOM_EVENT_STRING, myfunctionName);
}
```

Comment: could you post some of your code so we can see why unbind it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure that event delegation (what `.live()` uses) works with custom events?

Comment: Still, post your code so we don't guess, post an answer anyway with good intentions, and then have you tell us we didn't answer your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) attaches delegated event handlers to the document element so you'll have to unbind them from the document element this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/6522b/) shows how to unbind specific functions from live but not specific selected elements.
EDIT:
From the doc

Chaining methods is not supported. For example, $("a").find(".offsite, .external").live( ... ); is not valid and does not work as expected.

It is possible to unbind custom events, but you have to do it for all bound elements
In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/6522b/2/) the custom event only becomes unbound when all elements are unbound.

Comment: This seems to work well for the click event, but there are a few other details that seem to be affecting my code.  I think the difference may be that I am using trigger and a custom event.  My problem is not yet resolved.

Comment: @coder did you try unbinding the events from the document element also see edit.